# Some stuff about analytically that I don't understand

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a function $$f(z) = \frac{1 + 2z}{z^2 + z^3}$$
Observe that the function is analytic for $0 < |z| < 1$ but I don't understand this isn't analyticity defined as a function who is differentiable in some neighborhood of C?I know
that one of factors is $z - 1$ so at $1$ its not differentiable but wouldn't also the function be differentiable in values $> 1$ ?

such that
$0 < z < 1 \cup 1 < z < \infty$

Or am I missing something on my understanding of analytically?

Comment: You are correct in saying the function is analytic for $|z|>1$.  But the statement never said it wasn't.  It just said it was analytic for $|z|<1$.

Comment: oh I see so its just didn't mention it oke thanks alot stephen.

Answer (score 1):

Analytic means differentiable at every point in an open (connected) subset of $\mathbb C$. The punctured disk $0<|z|<1$ is an open (connected) subset of $\mathbb C$, and being analytic on it means that $f$ is differentiable at every point there.

For your particular function $f$, it is analytic on:

- the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$
- the open disk-complement $|z|>1$
- The three-punctured plane $\mathbb C\setminus\{0,i,-i\}$

On the disconnected union of the punctured disk and the disk-complement ($0<|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$), whether $f$ is analytic depends on the convention being used. The reason to demand that analytic is only on *connected* open sets is because then we can nicely state

**Theorem.** If two functions $f$ and $g$ analytic on the same domain, have the same power-series expansion around a point in that domain, then they are equal everywhere on that domain.